# wcf svclog to unc path?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a wcf service that I want to provide tracing for on a production server which I don't have local access to.

I would like to be able to have the .svclog file saved to a UNC path instead of a local disk.

Unfortunately, my attempts so far have given a very useless IIS7 500 internal server error message.  (even though custom errors are turned off)

My web.config trace config looks like this:

---

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true"
      switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="\\fileserver\rootshare\mysite\app_data\my.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

---

If I change the unc path to a local path and run it on my local webserver then all works fine

The app pool process runs as a restricted user account, that account has full permissions to the app_data folder...   any thoughts or obvious reason this wouldn't work?  (like maybe that listener doesn't support unc paths?)

Comment: needs not only permissions to the folder, but to the share.

Comment: The site hosting the service is hosted from the same share, it has permissions.  Thanks for the thought :)

Comment: `XmlWriterTraceListener` works fine with UNC paths, we're doing that w/o any problems. It even fails silently if the apppool identity doesn't have sufficient permissions on the share. So, your 500 error must have a different reason. Did you check the server Event Logs?

Comment: @ServiceGuy - Thanks for the info. That's the problem - I don't have server access, so can't map a drive and can't check event logs. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up robocopy to move the file from the local server to the UNC path is going to be a lot less trouble and potential security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the UNC fully trusted..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx